# Getting node.js to read files in html format

Tags: node.js

I am developing a small app in Node.js. I am just using Node.js for input and output.  The actual website is just running through nginx. The website has a Websocket connection with node.js and is primarily used for db manipulations.

One of the things I am trying to do is get node to send small pieces of html along with the data from the database. I tried the following code.

simplified:

```
    connection.on('message', function(message) {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/user.html', function(err, html){

            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }else{
                connection.sendUTF( JSON.stringify({
                    content: html,
                    data: {}
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I `console.log(html)` on the server or in the client I only get numbers back.

Anyone know what could be wrong.

**NOTE:** *I really want to stay away from stuff like `socket.io`, `express`, etc. Just keeping it as simple as possible and no fallbacks are needed.*

Comment: Step 3 of [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/)? Also, apparently you might want to replace "sendHeader" with "writeHead".

Comment: Where do I replace senHeader?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you don't specify an encoding for [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback), you will retrieve the raw buffer instead of the expected file contents.

Try calling it this way:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/views/user.html', 'utf8', function(err, html){
....
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I thought I read in documentation that it automatically defaults to utf8 when you do not specify any. Maybe I overlooked something. Will try this and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :)